# Adjacent DIVs click events being fired inappropriately

Tags: jquery, css, sprite

I'm having a bit of trouble setting up some icons/buttons using a combination of CSS Sprites, and DIVs with Click handlers that are dynamically set by jQuery.

Although I believe I'm positioning the DIVs side-by-side, and creating a click handler for each dynamically with jQuery, what I'm instead finding happens is that DIVs further to the right somehow acquire the click handlers for DIVs to their left in addition to the handler I intend them to have. So, for example, the click handler that I intend to be used for my "email" link is also opening my YouTube channel and my LinkedIn profile in addition to initiating a new email, since DIVs acting as buttons for those other functions are positioned to its left. Can anyone see what may be causing this behaviour?

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style>
        .icon
        {
            height: 68px;
            width: 56px;
            background-image: url('https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-HylbRS7gQyA/UVbSTXQYs5I/AAAAAAAAAs8/5J8Ij9mr_qk/s800/CommsIconsCSSSprites.png');
            position: relative;
            cursor:hand; cursor:pointer;
        }

        .youTube
        {
            background-position: 0px 0px;
            background-color:yellow;
        }

        .linkedIn
        {
            background-position: -56px 0px;
            left:56px;
            background-color:green;
        }

        .email
        {
            background-position: -112px 0px;
            left:56px;
            background-color:blue;
        }

        .rss
        {
            background-position: -168px 0px;
            left:56px;
            background-color:red;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function setCommsIcons() {
            $("#youTubeIcon").click(function () { window.open("http://www.youtube.com/user/RPPdotNet?feature=watch"); });
            $("#linkedInIcon").click(function () { window.open("http://www.linkedin.com/in/rachelppierson"); });
            $("#emailIcon").click(function () { window.location.href = "mailto:rachel.pierson@hotmail.co.uk"; });
            $("#rssIcon").click(function () { window.open("http://feeds.feedburner.com/RachelPiersonWorkInProgress"); });
        }

        function shiftImagesJustToSuitIE() {
            // Move the images up a fraction in i.e. to match other browsers
            if ($.browser.msie) {
                $.each($("#youTubeIcon, #linkedInIcon, #emailIcon, #rssIcon"), function (i, val) {
                    with (val) { val.style.pixelTop = val.style.pixelTop + 30; }
                });
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            setCommsIcons();
            shiftImagesJustToSuitIE();
        });

    </script>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="youTubeIcon" class="icon youTube" />
    <div id="linkedInIcon" class="icon linkedIn" />
    <div id="emailIcon" class="icon email" />
    <div id="rssIcon" class="icon rss" />
</body>
</html>
```

NB:

- The coloured backgrounds on the DIVs are there just to confirm to myself that I hadn't inadvertently made them too wide, thereby making them sit on top of one another.
- The relevant code has been separated out into its own HTML page just for test purposes. It actually lives in another place entirely. E.g., I have a master page that includes a reference to jQuery; it's not added just for this one page as in the example HTML shown. I've separated the above HTML out for the purposes of isolating this bug. The
  code above should run and exhibit the bug described if you cut and paste it as is into
  an HTML page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because you are self closing your divs and the click handler is getting applied to all divs contained within your target. Changing them to close properly will fix the issue.

How your markup actually renders:

```
<div id="youTubeIcon" class="icon youTube">
    <div id="linkedInIcon" class="icon linkedIn">
        <div id="emailIcon" class="icon email">
            <div id="rssIcon" class="icon rss">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How your markup should be written:

```
<div id="youTubeIcon" class="icon youTube"></div>
<div id="linkedInIcon" class="icon linkedIn"></div>
<div id="emailIcon" class="icon email"></div>
<div id="rssIcon" class="icon rss"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that quick and accurate answer. I have noticed some strange glitches with self-closing tags (e.g., the include link for the jQuery library in the above example doesn't work if you make its SCRIPT tag a self-closing tag). I'd never have guessed that was the problem here, though. 

Does that mean my "linkedInIcon", "emailIcon" and "rssIcon" DIVs were actually sitting *inside* the "youTubeIcon" DIV, because it was taking the self-closing "/>" that I'd intended just for the final DIV to actually be the closing tag of the first DIV?

Comment: That's exactly what it means :) Note that it will blow out your current intended styling once you close all your div's correctly.

Comment: Yes, I saw that styling issue. That's possibly a sign that I shouldn't be using DIVs at all, and instead have hyperlinks whose source images are set by CSS. In any case, thanks very much for your help. I've marked your answer as the right answer. I think I'm still too much of a newbie to upvote it as well, or I would do so.

Comment: You could change them to block links in your CSS and then style the background image. An example: a.myLinkClass {display:block;height:50px;width:50px;background:url('myimage.jpg') no-repeat;}

Comment: Block links are a new one on me. I've just been doing a bit of catchup: http://green-beast.com/blog/?p=74. I'll have a read through and see if I can make that approach work better. Thanks for the suggestion. Edit: I see you've added an example, thanks for that.

Comment: Forgot to add this before Rachel, but I wanted to come back and tell you how to look at the markup that is actually being generated. If we were to only look at the page source in this case we wouldn't have caught the issue, but instead I looked at the GENERATED source to catch the problem. You can do this in Firefox with Firebug's Inspector tool, or in Chrome under View > Developer > Developer Tools. Both have a little magnifying glass icon for the tool, and after you turn it on you can over over your problem areas in the rendered markup to see the html and css that applies to each element.

Comment: Cheers for that - great tip. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to conclude, in case anyone else finds themselves with this same issue. For speed I decided to stick with DIVs and make them display inline-block via CSS to fix the formatting issue that emerged once the initial bug had been fixed. Here's how the final code ended up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style>
        .icon
        {
            height: 68px;
            width: 56px;
            background-image: url('https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-HylbRS7gQyA/UVbSTXQYs5I/AAAAAAAAAs8/5J8Ij9mr_qk/s800/CommsIconsCSSSprites.png');
            position: relative;
            cursor:hand; cursor:pointer;
            display: inline-block;
            *display: inline;   /* just for Internet Explorer */
            zoom: 1;            /* just for Internet Explorer */
        }

        .youTube { background-position: 0px 0px; }

        .linkedIn { background-position: -56px 0px; }

        .email { background-position: -112px 0px; }

        .rss { background-position: -168px 0px; }
    </style>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function setCommsIcons() {
            $("#youTubeIcon").click(function () { window.open("http://www.youtube.com/user/RPPdotNet?feature=watch"); });
            $("#linkedInIcon").click(function () { window.open("http://www.linkedin.com/in/rachelppierson"); });
            $("#emailIcon").click(function () { window.location.href = "mailto:rachel.pierson@hotmail.co.uk"; });
            $("#rssIcon").click(function () { window.open("http://feeds.feedburner.com/RachelPiersonWorkInProgress"); });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            setCommsIcons();
        });

    </script>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="youTubeIcon" class="icon youTube"></div>
    <div id="linkedInIcon" class="icon linkedIn"></div>
    <div id="emailIcon" class="icon email"></div>
    <div id="rssIcon" class="icon rss"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Arguably I shouldn't be using jQuery at all since all it's doing is adding a Click handler and that could be done far more succinctly using hyperlinks as flemingslone indicated. The fact I'm using jQuery is just a legacy issue from a point in the development when jQuery was doing far more than merely setting a Click handler.